# Can I run SpringBootTests in a specific order?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test

When I'm running my SpringBootTests (using gradle) I have noticed that Test 3 always runs first. I would like understand how gradle decides the order of tests and I would like to be able to control the order and have Test 1 run first.
I know that JUnit5 allows this, however I'm interested to hear whether a similar feature exists for SpringBootTests.

Thank you!

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    void returnSomething1() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/hello",
                String.class)).contains("hello");

    @Test
    void returnSomething2() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/yo",
                String.class)).contains("yo");


    @Test
    void returnSomething3() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/bye",
                String.class)).contains("bye");
```

Comment: What platform are you using for running the tests? If you are using JUnit, then there is no reason why you could not use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation together with the `@TestMethodOrder` annotation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You're right, I needed to upgrade my Junit5 version to 5.4.0 and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @vox for your comment!

I was able to run the tests in order using the @TestMethodOrder annotation.
The reason it didn't work the first time round was my Junit5 version, I had to update it to 5.4.0.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class ControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Test
    @Order(1)
    void returnSomething1() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/hello",
                String.class)).contains("hello");

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    void returnSomething2() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/yo",
                String.class)).contains("yo");


    @Test
    @Order(3)
    void returnSomething3() {
        assertThat(this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/bye",
                String.class)).contains("bye");
```

Now they are running in the correct order.